# convert list of lists with time strings to seconds and find count times between

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists with time strings in them (this format `"17:04:20"`). I want to iterate through the list and count the times with a gap of 5 minutes or greater.

```
Eg. [[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]]
```

In this case the gap would be from `17:08:54 + 5 minutes` until `17:50:33`.

I've been trying to do this by replacing the `:` in  the time strings and then turning the value into seconds and putting them sorted into a list of lists. Then I wanted to go through the list and if the next value is more than 300 seconds record this value.

Im having trouble even changing the strings to second can anyone help ?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: For example if you take one of the list of lists as the times a button was pressed in a one hour period hence the format, if the button wasn't pressed for a period of 5 minutes. I want to record this time until the next time it is pressed and so on adding to the value if it there is a press and then subsequent 5 minute period. That list should then have a value representing that time, this time can only be counted from 17:00:00 -> 17:59:59. Ive tried implementing your code here https://github.com/ishikawa-rei/EPRO-CALC/blob/master/main.py but still dont understand exactly how your getting it

Comment: could you please post the output you expect for the input `[[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]]`

Comment: for example, starting countdown at 17:00:00, between that time and 17:05:00 there has been an entry
so at that point it will restart. The same case for 17:08:54. Five minutes after 17:08:54, there
has been no entry so from 17:13:54 until 17:50:33 and afterwards it doesnt go 5 minutes without being pushed again.
So the output would be 36m:33s. So for that entry alone it would be 
    [[],[],[2193],[]]

Comment: Updated the answer. But between `17:03:22","17:08:54` there is more than 300 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

arr = [[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]]

def convert(t):
    return datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S")

def append_start_end(element):
    if len(element) > 0:
        hour = element[0].split(":")[0]
        first = ["{}:00:00".format(hour)]
        last = ["{}:59:59".format(hour)]
        return first + element + last
    return []

result = []
for d in arr:
    d = append_start_end(d)
    result.append(
        [(convert(f[1]) - convert(f[0])  - timedelta(minutes=5) ).total_seconds()
         for f in zip(d[:-1], d[1:])
         if convert(f[1]) - convert(f[0])  > timedelta(minutes=5)]
    )

print(result)
```

**Updated**: removed steps in slices:

```
for f in zip(d[:-1:2], d[1::2])
```

Output now:

```
[[], [], [32.0, 2199.0], []]
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand  what the multiple values are is the 2199 the final value and what is the 32.

Comment: 32 seconds is time delta between 17:03:22 and 17:08:54(total 332-300 seconds). 2199 is time delta between 17:08:54 and 17:50:33 (total 2499-300 seconds)

Comment: im starting to get it, i tried with some other numbers, [[], [], ['17:03:50', '17:20:44', '17:25:00', '17:29:50', '17:33:50', '17:50:23'], []]. how can i get it to record the seconds from 5 minutes after the last input, eg if nothing has been detected for 5 minutes its starts recording from that moment not the previous time.

Comment: @dmnte please note - timedelta(minutes=5) added in `(convert(f[1]) - convert(f[0])  - timedelta(minutes=5) ).total_seconds()`

Comment: Thank you, one last thing [[], [], ['17:03:50', '17:20:44', '17:25:00', '17:29:50', '17:33:50', '17:50:23'], []] using this example the last value is 17:50:23 so at 55:23 it should record until 59:59 is that possible

Comment: @dmnte Added start and end of hour to array

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) module has most of what you need:

- `datetime` is a class that represents a moment in time, like `1970-01-01 17:03:22 UTC`.
- `datetime.strptime()` can be used to create a `datetime` from a string.
- The overloaded `-` operator on `datetime` objects gives you a `timedelta`, which has a `total_seconds()` method to convert it to seconds.

Note that the `time` class is closer to what you actually want to represent (a time of day, without the date part), but you cannot subtract two `time` objects.

Comment: Can you give an example of using the minus operator on a datetime.time object?

Comment: `my_time_2 - my_time_1`

Comment: if both of those are `datetime.time` objects, you'll get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, and that makes some sense too. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

use datetime module to convert a string into time like below:

```
from datetime import datetime

first_time = "17:08:54"

second_time = "17:50:33"

format = "%H:%M:%S"

time_delta = datetime.strptime(second_time, FMT) -datetime.strptime(first_time, FMT)

count = 0
gap = 5
if time_delta.seconds >= 5*60:
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give the location, time and delay. You can easily count the number of occurences using `len()`.

```
import datetime

event_times = [[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]]
threshold = 5*60

delayed = []
dt_prev_et = None
for i, ets in enumerate(event_times):
    for j, et in enumerate(ets):
        dt_et = datetime.datetime.strptime(et, "%H:%M:%S")
        if dt_prev_et is None:
            dt_prev_et = dt_et
            continue

        delay = (dt_et - dt_prev_et).seconds
        if delay > threshold:
            delayed.append((i, j, et, delay))

        dt_prev_et = dt_et

print(delayed)
```

Comment: Output: [(2, 1, '17:08:54', 332), (2, 2, '17:50:33', 2499)]

Answer (score 0):

I'd also use the datetime module, convert all the timestamps into a datetime object and use than the timedelta.

```
import datetime

inputarr = [[], [], ['17:03:22', '17:08:54', '17:50:33', '17:55:20'], []]

for currList in inputarr:
    dates = []
    for currTime in currList:
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(currTime, "%H:%M:%S"))
    elemDiff = [(j-i).seconds for i,j in zip(dates, dates[1:])]
    elemDiff.append(0) #added a 0 for same length of the lists
    for element in range(len(currList)):
        if elemDiff[element] > datetime.timedelta(minutes=5).seconds:
            print(currList[element])
```

Output:

```
17:03:22
17:08:54
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching arbitrary nested lists can be done with a recursive function

```
def gap_count(lst):

    count = 0
    timetag_pair = []

    for elem in lst:

        if isinstance(elem, list):

            # Recursive use of gap_count when a nested list is encountered.
            count += gap_count(elem)

        elif isinstance(elem, str):

            timetag_pair.append(datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M:%S'))

        if len(timetag_pair) == 2:

            if abs((timetag_pair[0].minute + timetag_pair[0].second / 60.0) -
                   (timetag_pair[1].minute + timetag_pair[1].second / 60.0)) >= 5:

                count += 1

            timetag_pair = []

    return count
```

If you call gap_count with your test list it should return 1.

```
lst = [[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]]
gap_count(lst)
> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get difference count using this code. Just pass your list to this function.

```
import datetime
def countDifference(date_list):
    final_count = []
    for inner_dt in date_list:
        count = 0
        new_list = []

        for dt_elem in inner_dt:
            new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_elem, "%H:%M:%S")
            total_seconds = new_date.hour*60*60 + new_date.minute*60 + new_date.second
            new_list.append(total_seconds)
        new_list.sort()

        for first, second in zip(new_list, new_list[1:]):
            if second - first >= 300: count+=1
        final_count.append((inner_dt, count))

    return final_count

print countDifference([[],[],["17:03:22","17:08:54","17:50:33","17:55:20"],[]])
```

Output:

```
[([], 0), ([], 0), (['17:03:22', '17:08:54', '17:50:33', '17:55:20'], 2), ([], 0)]
```